# how to redirect to a subdirectory depending on a certain day each year

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

i would like to use a .htaccess redirect to switch subdirectories each year on a certain date – so, on april 1 the redirect point lead to the subdirectory "summer", and on september 1 ist should point to the subdirectory "winter". how can i achieve this?

i have set up a basic .htaccess script pointing to the "summer" subdirectory:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?my-url.uk$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/summer/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /summer/$1
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?my-url.uk$
RewriteRule ^(/)?$ summer/index.php [L]
```

Answer (score 0):

Check this rules on the top of the .htaccess file. Use TIME_MON variable and check current month.

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{TIME_MON} =(04|05|06|07|08)
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?my-url.uk$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/summer/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /summer/$1

RewriteCond %{TIME_MON} =(04|05|06|07|08)
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?my-url.uk$
RewriteRule ^(/)?$ summer/index.php [L]

RewriteCond %{TIME_MON} =(01|02|03|09|10|11|12)
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?my-url.uk$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/winter/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /winter/$1

RewriteCond %{TIME_MON} =(01|02|03|09|10|11|12)
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?my-url.uk$
RewriteRule ^(/)?$ winter/index.php [L]
```

Comment: thank you for your input!
sadly, that does not work – there is no redirection at all, the top level content is being shown. could it be because of a non active mod_rewrite?

apart from that: does the month count really start with 01 and end with 12? should that not be 01 to 11?

Comment: TIME_MON - The current month (01, ..., 12) https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/expr.html

Comment: server host reports that mod_rewrite has always been active. so this cannot be the cause for jarek‘s script to be not working.